# Is a nested class name be considered as a current instantiation when it is used in a enclosing class template

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

According to the rule:
[temp.res#3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.res#3)

> When a qualified-id is intended to refer to a type that is **not a member of the current instantiation** ([temp.dep.type]) and its nested-name-specifier refers to a dependent type, it shall be prefixed by the keyword typename, forming a typename-specifier. If the qualified-id in a typename-specifier does not denote a type or a class template, the program is ill-formed.

That means, when a member of a current instantiation is used as a type-specifier it's not necessary to be prefixed by the keyword `typename`.

Please consider the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
template<class T>
struct A{
    struct B{
        struct C{
           A::B* p; //#5
        };
      B::C c;  //#3
      A::B::C d; //#4
    };
    A::B a;  //#1
    /*B::C b;*/  //#2
};
int main(){

}
```

The definition for current instantiation are:
[temp.dep.type#1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.dep.type#1)

> A name refers to the current instantiation if it is
>
> > 1. in the definition of a class template, a nested class of a class template, a member of a class template, or a member of a nested class of a class template, **the injected-class-name of the class template or nested class**,
> > 2. in the definition of a primary class template or a member of a primary class template, the name of the class template followed by the template argument list of the primary template (as described below) enclosed in <> (or an equivalent template alias specialization),
> > 3. in the definition of a nested class of a class template, the name of the nested class referenced as a member of the current instantiation, or

The declaration at `#1` is well-formed due to the first bullet of `current instantiation`. that is, at `#1`, the name `A` is the name of `current instantiation`, similar for `#3`.

`#4` is well-formed, because it obeys the third bullet of `current instantiation`, hence for `A::B`, where `B` is the name of current instantiation.

However, I can't understand why `#2` is ill-formed, in other words, it require the keyword `typename`, According to the first bullet, Isn't the name of the nested class be considered as a name of current instantiation?

Frankly, I don't know how to understand the first bullet. At least, I feel that the sentence is vague. Does it mean  these `injected-class-name`s(primary class name or nested class name) are all considered as a name of current instantiation as long as in one of the definitions listed in the sentence? `#2` seems not support this interpretation.

What I can infer from the example is, The `enclosing class name` in a nested class can be considered as a name of current instantiation but not the other way around.  If understand the sentence in this way, It can understand why the code at `#5` is well-formed.

So, how to read the first bullet correctly? Do you agree the sentence is vague?

Comment: `type` is not a keyword. Do you mean `typename` ?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 yes, a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is a nested class name be considered as a current instantiation when it is used in a enclosing class template?

No.

However, as with many other passages of the standard, paragraph [[temp.dep.type]/1.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.dep.type#1.1) is indeed a mouthful:

> A name refers to the *current instantiation* if it is
>
> - *(1.1)* in the definition of a class template, a nested class of a class template, a member of a class template, or a member of a nested class of a class template, the injected-class-name of the class template or nested class, [...]

and we may need to break it down into the different cases to see that it does not apply to a nested-class-name when in the definition of class template where, in turn, the nested class is defined:

> A name refers to the *current instantiation* if it is,
>
> - in the definition of **a class template**, the injected-class-name of **the class template** ["or nested class" does not apply for this case]
> - in the definition of **a nested class** of **a class template**, the injected-class-name of **the class template** or **[the] nested class**
> - in the definition of a member of **a class template**, the injected-class-name of **the class template** ["or nested class" does
>   not apply for this case]
> - in the definition of a member of **a nested class** of **a class template**, the injected-class-name of **the class template** or **[the] nested class**

where I have **emphasized** the connection of the *"if it is in the definition **of a X** (**of a Y**), the injected-class-name of **the X** (**or [the] Y**)"*. Noting particularly that when the definition is of a class template (when X is class template), there is no "**a** nested class" to refer back to at the latter part, when describing the "*injected-class-name* of **the** ...".

Conversely, there is no way interpret [temp.dep.type]/1.1 as

> " in the definition of a class template, the injected-class-name of the class template **or any nested class of the class template** "

Thus, in your example, `#2`, we are *in the definition of a class template* (namely `A`), meaning only the name of *the class template* itself, namely `A`, refers to the *current instantiation*.

---

> Do you agree the sentence is vague?

Given the above, I would not say that it is vague (as this would imply some *ambiguity*, which I cannot see), but possible needlessly complex. It could arguably be clearer if [[temp.dep.type]/1.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.dep.type#1.1) was split into two separate paragraphs:

> A name refers to the *current instantiation* if it is
>
> - *(1.1a)* in the definition of a class template, or a member of a class template, the injected-class-name of the class template,
> - *(1.1b)* in the definition of a nested class of a class template, or a member of a nested class of a class template, the injected-class-name of the class template or nested class, [...]

Comment: A wonderful answers. you have described that bullet clearly. I think the issue of the first bullet is, it does not separate the concept, that is where are these places in which the `nested class name` can be the current instantiation. As I said, the sentence always leads me to read it as that the `nested class name` would be considered as a current name if it is in the definition given in the first bullet.